# Final value theorem for closed system

Tags: laplace-transform, control-theory

We have a system with output given by

$\frac{Y(s)}{R(s)} = \frac{F(s)G(s)}{1+F(s)G(s)}$

where $F(s)G(s) = K\frac{s+1}{s^2+s+1}$.

Let $K=4$ and $R(s) = 10/s$. Using the final value theorem, calculate the steady state error of the system.

Now, I thought the error would be given by $\lim_{s \rightarrow 0} \frac{10\cdot F(s)G(s)}{1+F(s)G(s)}$, but the solution says to calculate $\frac{10}{1+F(s)G(s)}$. Can anyone explain why?

Comment: Because you are interested in the error not the output. So you want $\lim_{s\rightarrow 0}(R(s)- Y(s))=0$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have to  find the steady state error
$$\lim_{t\rightarrow\infty}(r(t)-y(t))$$
According to the final value theorem
$$\lim_{t\rightarrow\infty}(r(t)-y(t))=\lim_{s\rightarrow 0}\left[s(R(s)-Y(s))\right]$$
The Laplace transform of the error is given by
$$R(s)-Y(s)=R(s)-\frac{F(s)G(s)}{1+F(s)G(s)}R(s)=\frac{1}{1+F(s)G(s)}R(s)$$
Hence, for a step reference with Laplace transform $R(s)=10/s$ the steady state error value can be derived by
$$\lim_{t\rightarrow\infty}(r(t)-y(t))=\lim_{s\rightarrow 0}\left[s\frac{1}{1+F(s)G(s)}\frac{10}{s}\right]=\lim_{s\rightarrow 0}\left[\frac{10}{1+F(s)G(s)}\right]$$